# Python - Adding fractions

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am trying to add fractions and I'm wondering how to get an input of 1 1/4 instead of (1, 1, 4). This code is also suppose to add fractions without using the Class Fractions. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
   class Fraction:

def _gcd(a ,b):
  while b:
    a, b = b, a % b
  return(a)

def _lcm(a ,b):
  return(a * b // Fraction._gcd(a, b))

def __init__(self, numerator, denominator) :

   if denominator < 0:
      denominator *= -1
      numerator *= -1

   self.num = numerator
   self.den = denominator

def __add__ (self, other) :
  new_denominator = Fraction._lcm(self.den, other.den)
  new_numerator = self.num*new_denominator//self.den + other.num*new_denominator//other.den

  GCD = Fraction._gcd(new_numerator, new_denominator)
  new_numerator = new_numerator // GCD
  new_denominator = new_denominator // GCD

  if new_numerator > new_denominator :
    whole = new_numerator // new_denominator
    new_numerator = new_numerator%new_denominator
    return (whole, new_numerator, new_denominator)
  else :
    return (new_numerator, new_denominator)
def __sub__(self, other):


  temp = Fraction(-1 * other.num, other.den)
  return(self + temp)



num1 = Fraction(2,4)
num2 = Fraction(15,20)
print(num1.__add__(num2))
```

Comment: can you please reduce your "problem" to your actual problem including desired behavior and so on?

Comment: I'm asking on how to get an output of 1 1/4 instead of 1, 1, 4

Comment: Do you mean you want to return it as a string instead of tuple? `return "{} {}/{}".format(whole, new_numerator, new_denominator)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very poorly explained...

If that is a formatting problem, `"{} {}/{}".format(1, 1, 4)` will give you `"1 1/4"` as a string, is it what you want? Then you can adapt it to work with your code's variables.

If I didn't get it right, you should probably try to better explain your issue.

Refs:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

https://pyformat.info/

Comment: sorry i didn't explain it clearly, im really new to this stuff....

Comment: It's OK, I'm sure your next question on SO will be much more detailed :)
Everyone has the right to be a beginner.